# Generating a pseudopotential for graphene: Is it done on an individual carbon atom, or on an entire unit cell of graphene?

Tags: molecular-modeling, pseudopotentials

Let's take the example of a 2D graphene layer. The objective is to do an electronic calculation with only the valence electrons with a plane wave basis. Hence the need to pseudize the core electrons through an all-electron (AE) calculation.

**Does the AE calculation contain only one carbon atom in my case?**
**Or is it done on a primitive cell with the same basis functions as the valence electron (VE) only calculation?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pseudopotentials tend to be provided for ***individual elements*** in the periodic table.

For example, if you go to the [Pseudopotential library](https://pseudopotentiallibrary.org/) and click on the element C, you will get access to many files that contain pseudopotential data for the element C. For example, I see `C.awfn` in the list of available pseudopotentials and when I click on it, I get [this](https://pseudopotentiallibrary.org/recipes/C/CEPP/C.awfn) which starts with the following:

```
Atomic C  wave function in real space
Atomic number
  6
Total number of orbitals
 2
From 1 configurations, orbitals 2S(2)2P(2) [PZ].
Number of up, downspin electrons
n/a
States
n/a
Radial grid (a.u.)
 957
    0.000000000000000E+00
    0.167862832095561E-05
    0.338140915368192E-05
    0.510869001038132E-05
    0.686082340334615E-05
```

I have not seen pseudopotentials that were built specifically for entire molecules or unit cells, although I don't see why it wouldn't be ***possible.***

The Quantum ESPRESSO website also provides a pseudopotential library [here](http://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/legacy_tables) and a list of other pseudopotential libraries [here](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/other-resources/) (which includes [Pseudo Dojo](http://www.pseudo-dojo.org/) which was created by my co-author Michiel van Setten). Most if not all of those resources will provide you with a periodic table from which you can select a periodic table element and get its pseudopotentials (and I haven't seen such a database that provides you with various materials like graphene, graphane, or graphyne, and allows you to download a pseudopotential that is built specifically for one of those materials).